# Percental difference between byte array

Tags: c#, arrays, compare, byte, diff

I've got 100,000 fixed length byte arrays (of length 150) which I want to compare against each other. I want to identify any of the byte arrays in my 100,000 which have over 90% of their byte values in the same place and with the same value as one or more of the other arrays.

For example:

Test against
1: A4343FBC2321FFD135423232EF.....(match against 2 (100%) and 3 (96%))

2: A4343FBC2321FFD135423232EF.....(match against 1 (100%) and 3 (96%))

3: A4343FBC2321FFD135423232E1.....(match against 1 (96%) and 2(96%))

4: B465454ABC32321323AAAAAFFF.....(no match)

5: FED124343214343FE3232FE323.....(match against 7 (100%))

6: FED12434321431121212121212.....(NO MATCH, less than 90% similarity)

7: FED124343214343FE3232FE323.....(match against 5 (100%))

I want to write this using C# and run it as fast as possible as I'm likely to require it to run with over a million byte arrays to compare.

Comment: So write some code see how it goes..

Comment: Stack overflow cannot do your homework for you...

Comment: Best of luck - with a million 150 byte arrays you are looking at in the region of 7.5 x 10 power 13 byte comparisons. If you could manage 1 million comparisons a second, that would take a bit over 2 years.

Comment: Unfortunately, you will likely have to do a lot of comparisons anyway, if most arrays share similarities: for each set of `m` arrays which are somehow clustered into a same "bucket", you will need `O(m^2)` comparisons to confirm the exact percentage. Your best case will be when very few arrays are similar enough, in which case you will be able to assert they are all different in `~O(n)`. What are you trying to do, actually?

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

As any O(n^2) solution seems to be too slow for n = 100,000 you may want to use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality-sensitive_hashing

I'm not sure it will help, but it should give you some direction.